# Should subpackages have their own go.mod file?

Tags: go

I have a project that looks similar to this `tree`:

```
. proj
├── README.md
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── subpackage
│   ├── one.go
│   ├── two.go
│   ├── three.go
│   └── four.go
├── main.go
```

In `main.go` I am importing a struct and some methods via `github.com/username/proj/subpackage`.

I am not using subpackage in any other projects (only this project).

Should I have a separate `go.mod` file within `subpackage/` in addition to the `go.mod` file in project root? And consequently should the subpackage be listed in project-root's `go.sum` file?

If not, would I need it in the case where the subpackage directory/package is being used in a completely separate project?

Comment: A module is a "set of packages versioned together" to be used as a set from other code. It is possible but uncommon to have several different modules  with different versions on one repo. But these are extremely rare cases. Put all your packages of one project into one module. Note that there are no "subpackages": All packages are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A separate `go.mod` for subpackages is unnecessary. With such a go.mod file it is possible to separately tag the subpackage with a different version than the root package. This usecase is only needed in very specialized instances, where you want to have different versions for packages inside the same repository, so do not do that.

You do not have to modify go.sum manually at all. It should only be modified by the go-tooling (go get, go build), automatically.

Even if the subpackage is used inside another project by importing it, you do not have to give the subpackage a different version. When this subpackage is imported the go-tool will search for the root of the git repository, download the repository automatically with `go get` and make it available for importing.